# Reserved name in Snakemake?

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, snakemake

I use `Snakemake` version **7.12.1** and I get the following error while trying to execute a pipeline:

> AttributeError: invalid name for input, output, wildcard, params or
> log: pop is reserved for internal use

I normally use the word `pop` as the wildcard for population with no issue. After the raised error, I made it changed to another word and it looks like the error is gone. Would someone confirm that pop is now a reserved name or there is another explanation for? I checked the snakemake manual and there is no any related notification.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Would someone confirm that pop is now a reserved name or there is another explanation for?

Yes, `pop` is reserved because internally some processes use `.pop` method to remove items from the directives.

Internally, the directives (input/output/etc) are stored as a `Namedlist` which inherits methods from the `list`. So almost all the methods defined for `list` (and `Namedlist`) will trigger this error, e.g. `remove`, `reverse`. There are two hard-coded `whitelisted` exceptions: `index` and `sort`.

This change has been [added a couple of years ago](https://github.com/snakemake/snakemake/commit/2cc2a9b8ee7d8814125553b098b521e023294b60), so you must have been running a much older `snakemake` version.

Here's a small Snakefile for testing:

```py
rule all:
    input: 'test.txt'
    
rule test:
    output:
        # this will err
        pop = 'test.txt'
    shell: 'echo {output}'
```